# how to solve the error Must Declare the Scalar Variable

Tags: vb.net

I have encountered an error in vb.net. It shows Must declare the scalar variable "@FieldDeg". I can only insert data into the database by using the insertSql but not insertSql2 because it keeps showing the error at the FieldDeg, can anyone help with this codes.
Thanks alot.
Here is my codes.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class CV
    Dim conn As SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim cmd2 As SqlCommand
    Dim Genders() As String = {"Male", "Female"}


    Private Sub CV_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        cboGender.Items.AddRange(Genders)
        cboGender.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
        cboGender.SelectedIndex = 0

        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Image Files (*.bmp;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.JPEG;*.PNG"

        txtField1.Enabled = False
        txtMajor1.Enabled = False
        txtInstitute1.Enabled = False
        txtGrade1.Enabled = False
        mskGradDate1.Enabled = False

        txtField2.Enabled = False
        txtMajor2.Enabled = False
        txtInstitute2.Enabled = False
        txtGrade2.Enabled = False
        mskGradDate2.Enabled = False

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        Dim insertSql As String
        Dim insertSql2 As String

        conn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Assignment.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30")

        insertSql = "Insert into [Personal Information] ([Full Name], [Address], [Phone Number], [Mobile Number], [Email], [Age], [Date of Birth], [Nationality], [Gender], [Marital Status], [IC Or Passport], [Permanent Residence]) Values (@Fullname, @Address, @Phone, @Mobile, @Email, @Age, @DOB, @Nationality, @Gender, @Marital, @IC, @Residence)"

        insertSql2 = "Insert into [Education Background] ([Field of Study Deg], [Major Deg], [Institute Or University Deg], [Grade Deg],[Graduation Date Deg], [Field of Study Dip], [Major Dip], [Institute Or University Dip], [Grade Dip], [Graduation Date Dip]) Values (@FieldDeg, @MajorDeg, @InstituteDeg, @GradeDeg, @GradDateDeg, @FieldDip, @MajorDip, @InstituteDip, @GradeDip, @GradDateDip)"

        If (txtFullname.Text = "" Or txtAddress.Text = "" Or mskPhone.Text = "" Or mskMobile.Text = "" Or txtEmail.Text = "" Or mskAge.Text = "" Or mskAge.Text = "" Or mskDOB.Text = "" Or txtNationality.Text = "" Or txtMarital.Text = "" Or txtIC.Text = "" Or txtPR.Text = "") Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter all information for Curriculum Vitae.", "Data Field Cannot Be Empty", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Else
            'open the database connection
            conn.Open()

            'create the command object
            cmd = New SqlCommand(insertSql, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fullname", txtFullname.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", mskPhone.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", mskMobile.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", mskAge.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", mskDOB.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nationality", txtNationality.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", cboGender.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Marital", txtMarital.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IC", txtIC.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Residence", txtPR.Text)

            cmd2 = New SqlCommand(insertSql2, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FieldDeg", txtField1.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MajorDeg", txtMajor1.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InstituteDeg", txtInstitute1.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GradeDeg", txtGrade1.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GradDateDeg", mskGradDate1.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FieldDip", txtField2.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MajorDip", txtMajor2.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InstituteDip", txtInstitute2.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GradeDip", txtGrade2.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GradDateDip", mskGradDate2.Text)

            'executes the INSERT SQL statement
            Dim status As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Dim status2 As Integer = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
            If status > 0 And status2 > 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Curriculum Vitae has been recorded successfully", "CV Recorded", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Curriculum Vitae cannot be recorded. Please check the cv details.", "CV Record Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End If
            conn.Close()  'close the connection
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnBrowse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBrowse.Click
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        Pic.ImageLocation = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    End Sub

    Private Sub chkDegree_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkDegree.CheckedChanged
        If chkDegree.Checked Then
            txtField1.Enabled = True
            txtMajor1.Enabled = True
            txtInstitute1.Enabled = True
            txtGrade1.Enabled = True
            mskGradDate1.Enabled = True
        Else
            txtField1.Enabled = False
            txtMajor1.Enabled = False
            txtInstitute1.Enabled = False
            txtGrade1.Enabled = False
            mskGradDate1.Enabled = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub chkDiploma_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkDiploma.CheckedChanged
        If chkDiploma.Checked Then
            txtField2.Enabled = True
            txtMajor2.Enabled = True
            txtInstitute2.Enabled = True
            txtGrade2.Enabled = True
            mskGradDate2.Enabled = True
        Else
            txtField2.Enabled = False
            txtMajor2.Enabled = False
            txtInstitute2.Enabled = False
            txtGrade2.Enabled = False
            mskGradDate2.Enabled = False
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: That is a great deal of data you are putting in Educational Background table but how are you going to tell who all that belongs to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the line: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FieldDeg", txtField1.Text)` should reference cmd2 instead.  You're adding parameters to the wrong command.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, you're "checking" subroutines can be simplified as follows:

```
Private Sub chkDiploma_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkDiploma.CheckedChanged
    txtField2.Enabled = chkDiploma.Checked
    txtMajor2.Enabled = chkDiploma.Checked
    txtInstitute2.Enabled = chkDiploma.Checked
    txtGrade2.Enabled = chkDiploma.Checked
    mskGradDate2.Enabled = chkDiploma.Checked
End Sub
```

Comment: Even better would be to resolve `chkDiploma.Checked` once and the use the local Boolean for each text box. `Dim chk As Boolean = chkDiploma.Checked`  Then `txtField2.Enabled = chk`

Comment: @Mary  I assume that the compiler just treats chkDiploma.Checked as an address so it only gets evaluated once.  No?

Comment: You may be correct with some optimization that I can't see but checking the IL is seems to require more code to get the check box then its checked property 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the validation code to a separate method. I put a comment there regarding additional validation. I used OrElse instead of Or. This short circuits the If statement stopping the checking as soon as it finds a True condition.

Keep your connection and commands local to the methods where they are used. These objects need to be closed and disposed. `Using...End` Using blocks handle this for you even if there is an error.

Declare the 2 status variables outside the `Using` block.

Cudos for using parameters! For Sql Server use the `.Add` method for parameters. See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html

I had to guess at the datatype and size of your fields. Check your database for the actual values.

Open the connection at the last possible moment, directly before the `.Execute...`

I declared the status variables outside the Using block so we could use them after the connection is disposed. We wouldn't want the connection open when we show a MessageBox. The user could have gone to lunch.

I am still concerned that the data in Educational Background is not tied to Personal Information. Normally, there would be a foreign key field in Educational Background that references the primary key in Personal Information. If this is the case you would need to tack on a `Select Scope_Identity` to the first command, call `.ExecuteScalar` instead of nonquery, and use the resulting value for a parameter in the second query.

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    If Not ValidateInput() Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim Status As Integer
    Dim Status2 As Integer
    Using conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Assignment.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"),
                cmd As New SqlCommand("Insert into [Personal Information] ([Full Name], [Address], [Phone Number], [Mobile Number], [Email], [Age], [Date of Birth], [Nationality], [Gender], [Marital Status], [IC Or Passport], [Permanent Residence]) Values (@Fullname, @Address, @Phone, @Mobile, @Email, @Age, @DOB, @Nationality, @Gender, @Marital, @IC, @Residence)", conn),
                cmd2 As New SqlCommand("Insert into [Education Background] ([Field of Study Deg], [Major Deg], [Institute Or University Deg], [Grade Deg],[Graduation Date Deg], [Field of Study Dip], [Major Dip], [Institute Or University Dip], [Grade Dip], [Graduation Date Dip]) Values (@FieldDeg, @MajorDeg, @InstituteDeg, @GradeDeg, @GradDateDeg, @FieldDip, @MajorDip, @InstituteDip, @GradeDip, @GradDateDip)", conn)
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@Fullname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = txtFullname.Text
            .Add("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = txtAddress.Text
            .Add("@Phone", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = mskPhone.Text
            .Add("@Mobile", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = mskMobile.Text
            .Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = txtEmail.Text
            .Add("@Age", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = mskAge.Text
            .Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = mskDOB.Text
            .Add("@Nationality", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = txtNationality.Text
            .Add("@Gender", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = cboGender.Text
            .Add("@Marital", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = txtMarital.Text
            .Add("@IC", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = txtIC.Text
            .Add("@Residence", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = txtPR.Text
        End With
        With cmd2.Parameters
            .Add("@FieldDeg", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = txtField1.Text
            .Add("@MajorDeg", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = txtMajor1.Text
            .Add("@InstituteDeg", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = txtInstitute1.Text
            .Add("@GradeDeg", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = txtGrade1.Text
            .Add("@GradDateDeg", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = mskGradDate1.Text
            .Add("@FieldDip", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = txtField2.Text
            .Add("@MajorDip", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = txtMajor2.Text
            .Add("@InstituteDip", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = txtInstitute2.Text
            .Add("@GradeDip", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = txtGrade2.Text
            .Add("@GradDateDip", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = mskGradDate2.Text
        End With
        conn.Open()
        Status = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Status2 = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    If Status > 0 AndAlso Status2 > 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Curriculum Vitae has been recorded successfully", "CV Recorded", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Curriculum Vitae cannot be recorded. Please check the cv details.", "CV Record Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If
End Sub
Private Function ValidateInput() As Boolean
    'You will want to add additional validation if any of your database fields require numbers or dates.
    'Use the various .TryParse methods to validate
    If txtFullname.Text = "" OrElse txtAddress.Text = "" OrElse mskPhone.Text = "" OrElse mskMobile.Text = "" OrElse txtEmail.Text = "" OrElse mskAge.Text = "" OrElse mskAge.Text = "" OrElse mskDOB.Text = "" OrElse txtNationality.Text = "" OrElse txtMarital.Text = "" OrElse txtIC.Text = "" OrElse txtPR.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter all information for Curriculum Vitae.", "Data Field Cannot Be Empty", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Return False
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```